# What is the correct way of updating a HTML Input element after data changed in a lit-element?

Tags: javascript, html, web-component, lit

I have a bug in an application using [lit-element](https://lit.dev) custom web-components: When manually editing a HTML Input element, changes in the internal component state are no longer reflected in that element. However, *before* doing any manual edits, the values are correctly reflected.

I seem to miss some knowledge on how HTML element attributes work. Either that, or I lack knowledge around lit-element.

My suspicion is on the way the DOM node works in detail. But I may be wrong. It seems that as soon as a manual edit it made to the "Input" element, its behaviour changes and it always keeps the user-value, even if something else changes. Conversely though, getting a reference to the input-element in the dev-tools console (via right-click, inspect and then using the `$0` variable) allows me to do `$0.value = 'foo'` and the value 'foo' *will* be displayed in the field.

So with that last experiment I am not so sure anymore. Has it something to do with `lit` after all? I'm all out of ideas...

It seems to be a very common thing to do so I would assume that `lit` should support this, and that I'm doing something wrong somewhere...

I could listen to change events and then set the `.value` propery manually. But that seems unnecessarily "manual". So how do I do this correctly?

I managed to reduce the issue to a really small reproducible example. I wrote it up on codepen here: https://codepen.io/exhuma/pen/eYrNQJK

For reference, here's the code using and defining the component:

```html
<!-- using the component -->
<text-field-demo></text-field-demo>
<script type="module" src="path-to-ts-file" />
```

```js
// The TypeScript file to load in the HTML
// document which uses the component

import {
  LitElement,
  html,
  customElement,
  state
} from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/lit@2.3.1";

export class TextFieldDemo extends LitElement {
  // [does not work in CodePen] @state()
  data = 0;

  doIncrement() {
    // This increment should be reflected in the UI
    // even *after* a manual edit was made in
    // the text-field
    this.data += 1;
    console.log(this.data);
    this.requestUpdate();
  }

  /**
   * Update the local component state with the new value from the DOM
   * @param evt The change event
   */
  updateObject(evt) {
    this.data = Number.parseInt(evt.target.value, 10);
  }

  render() {
    return html`
      Object:
      <input type="text" value=${this.data} @change=${this.updateObject} />
      <button @click=${this.doIncrement}>Increment and log</button>
      <pre>Data in non-interactive element: ${this.data}</pre>
    `;
  }
}
customElements.define("text-field-demo", TextFieldDemo);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Short answer

Bind to the property, not the attribute:

```
<input type="text" .value=${this.data} />
```

### Long answer with detailed explanation

The `value` **attribute** of an `HTMLInputElement` serves only as an **initial value** (available as `defaultValue` *property* on the DOM object) **at first render**; changing the `value` attribute later neither has any visual impact, nor does it reflect to the `value` **property** (which is always in sync with what the input displays). It does change the `defaultValue` property, though.

I don't have exact reason for this design decision for you, but it is helpful if you want to check if an input's content has been modified `(el.value !== el.defaultValue)`.

See also https://github.com/lit/lit/issues/743#issuecomment-454042498

So to fix your problem, put a `.` before the  `value` in your render method (which tells lit to bind to the **property** rather than to an *attribute*):

```
<input type="text" .value=${this.data} />
```

If all your change handler does is writing user input back into your state, that's already being done for you.

Also see https://github.com/lit/lit/issues/743#issuecomment-454057588

Since this is a very common source of errors, `eslint-plugin-lit` (which your project apparently isn't using) even has [a rule for this](https://github.com/43081j/eslint-plugin-lit/blob/master/docs/rules/no-value-attribute.md) (also see [this explanation](https://github.com/43081j/eslint-plugin-lit/issues/20)).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. It makes sense and the attribute/property difference is the piece of the puzzle I was missing and aligns perfectly with my suspicions. I further assume that this is independent from the framework (as it is a "DOM thing) and similar things happen in Vue, React & co. I know you said you are unaware of the reason behind this design-decision. But do you maybe have a link to reference docs on this? I would like to deepen my understanding. If not, that's fine. The most important thing "clicked" for me now :)

Comment: Incidentally, this also helped me understand how to properly use `textarea` element. As those *don't* have a `value` **attribute** I tended to overcomplicate my code. But they *have* a `value` **property** which allows me to use the same technique and remove a *lot* of cruft from my code.

Comment: Yeah, for `textarea` the content serves as the initial value. Great to hear you found some missing puzzle pieces!

Comment: You never stop learning ;) I'm always excited when I find something I don't understand. It means the knowledge hammer will drop soon and I go away a tiny bit smarter. This issue was one such occasions :)